# How to use the new H3 layer

Tags: kepler.gl, h3

I've checked out the newest code in the github master branch of kepler.gl and I'm running the demo. But I don't see the H3HexGrid layer option. How do I use it? The git commits seem to indicate it can be used in the demo app. Also how do I load sample data from here: sampleH3Data from './data/sample-hex-id-csv';

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get the sample data to load by uncommenting line 86 in app.js of the demo app so that _loadSampleData(); runs. But I still don't see the new layer option. I still only see the original 9 layers in the Layers selection. H3Layer is still missing from the ui.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a dataset containing h3 hexagon id. Kepler.gl will look for column name `hex_id` or `hexagon_id` to automatically create an H3 layer.

You can save `/data/sample-hex-id-csv.js` to a `.csv` file by removing the ``` export default `` and ``; ``` at the beginning and end of the file. Then drag and drop it into kepler.gl app to see how it works.